# Using Javascript control with Checkbox in a ListView

Tags: javascript, asp.net, listview, checkbox

Hi there is a way to use a control Javascript that erase "qtaTextBox" and "costoTextBox"  when I check "selezionatoCheckBox"?
My problem is the management of the elements in the listview, without it I would be able to do
Thanks

```
<ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color: #E0FFFF;color: #333333;">
            <td><asp:Label ID="idLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="attivitaLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("attivita") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="tariffa_studioLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("tariffa_studio") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="noteLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("note") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="dirittiLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("diritti") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="costo_realeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("costo_reale") %>' /></td>             
            <td><asp:CheckBox ID="selezionatoCheck" runat="server" Text="Presente" /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="qtaTextBox" runat="server" /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="costoTextBox" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

> erase "qtaTextBox" and "costoTextBox" when I check
>   "selezionatoCheckBox"

You can bind an event handler to the click event of the checkbox and clear the textboxes when it is clicked, similar to this:

```
var selCheck = document.getElementById('selezionatoCheckBox');
var qtaText = document.getElementById('qtaTextBox');
var costoText = document.getElementById('costoTextBox');

selCheck.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(this.checked){ // if not needed if you always want to clear
        qtaText.value = '';
        costoText.value = '';
    }
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sPbnz/) - Clear text when check is clicked

---

If you have those controls in each row of a list you might want to give each textbox/checkbox control data-attributes i.e: `data-row` and `data-id` for selection and grouping. Something similar to:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input data-row="1" data-id="qtaTextBox" type="text"></input>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input data-row="1" data-id="costoTextBox" type="text"></input>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input data-row="1" data-id="selezionatoCheckBox" type="checkbox"></input>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input data-row="2" data-id="qtaTextBox" type="text"></input>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input data-row="2" data-id="costoTextBox" type="text"></input>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input data-row="2" data-id="selezionatoCheckBox" type="checkbox"></input>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Using a `data-id` attribute allows selection of multiple controls as just `id` will only return the first match otherwise.

Using a `data-row` attribute would allow you to group the controls so the checkbox of row 1 will only ever clear the textboxes of row 1 as well, simiilar to this:

```
var selChecks = document.querySelectorAll('[data-id=selezionatoCheckBox]');
var index;
var checkLength = selChecks.length;

for (index = 0; index < checkLength; index++) {
    selChecks[index].addEventListener('click', function () {
        var qtaText = document.querySelector('[data-id="qtaTextBox"][data-row="' + this.dataset.row + '"]');
        var costoText = document.querySelector('[data-id="costoTextBox"][data-row="' + this.dataset.row + '"]');

        if (this.checked) { // if not needed if you always want to clear
            qtaText.value = '';
            costoText.value = '';
        }
    });
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/56XEu/) - Clearing text in the same row as the check

---

Comment: @P_R: If you are in a list where controls are repeated you need to give the controls something you can group and identify them with other than just the `id`. In your post you seem to have a table with a set of controls in each row. I added an example on how to achieve this. Don't get hung up on the `data-row` value, you can put in anything you want in there as long as it is unique between each "row" but matches between each control on the same row.